# Is integration smooth?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, synthetic-differential

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $\varphi:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which assigns to every $f\in C^\infty(M)$ the value $\int_M fdV.$

In a smooth topos which is a well adapted model, does the morphism  $\overline{\varphi}:R^M\rightarrow R$ corresponding to $\varphi$ exist?

Comment: Say more about the volume measure...is it given with the manifold?  Does it come from a metric?  or from an embedding into R^n?

Comment: I'm especially interested in the case it comes from a metric, but if there is a discussion for other cases, I want to know that.

Comment: The answer seems to be yes for Riemannian M, using Anders Kock's construction of a "volume form as volume of infinitesimal simplices", https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006008

Comment: I find it hard to believe that it matters how the volume form is given, since by Moser's theorem any two volume forms on a compact manifold are equivalent up to a diffeomorphism .

Comment: @MattF. I skimmed Kock's article but couldn't see the result the OP wants there. Could you be more specific about how it follows from the results in the article?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, on further reflection I agree.  The problem is that there seems to be no standard definition of  either compactness or integration over general regions in SDG, but only integration over cubes.  I thought that once we had a good volume form, we could appeal to an existing theory of integration for the rest, but apparently not.